# neo4j finish() not recognized

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

This is part of the code:

```
try {
    myFirstNode = graphDb.createNode();
    myFirstNode.setProperty("name", "Node 1 is my name");
    mySecondNode = graphDb.createNode();
    mySecondNode.setProperty("name", "Node 2 is my name");

    //Relations
    myRelationship = myFirstNode.createRelationshipTo(mySecondNode, RelTypes.KNOWS);
    myRelationship.setProperty("relationship-type", "knows");

    myString = (myFirstNode.getProperty("name").toString())
            + " " + (myRelationship.getProperty("relationship-type").toString())
            + " " + (mySecondNode.getProperty("name").toString());

    System.out.println(myString);

    tx.success();

} finally {
    tx.finish();
}
```

the method finish marks an error. "The method finish() is undefined for the type Transaction"

I created my project in maven and the neo4j version is 3.2.6

What did I miss?

By the way, to test the program I commented the line **tx.finish()**, in the database information, **Property Keys** the name and relation is displayed, but no node is displayed. (no changes, no records). It has to do with the tx.finish method?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

The [Transaction](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html) interface has no `finish()` method.

You should use `tx.close()` instead.

Comment: I can see that many things, have changed from neo4j, it used to eork with tx.finish()